# Plain text emails with Rails/Slim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

I've just converted my Rails 4 app from Haml to Slim. Everything went well but I can't get plain text emails to work.

I used the [haml2slim](https://github.com/slim-template/haml2slim) converter. It automatically changed my filenames to filename.text.plain.slim.

When I run my tests, each one related to Mailers fails with an "ActionView::MissingTemplate" error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your template name should be `filename.text.slim` instead of `filename.text.plain.slim`.

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks! Also removed 'plain:' from the top which was a leftover from HAML.